# Find CodePipeline CIDR to add it to EC2 Security Group inbound rules

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, aws-codepipeline

We are using AWS CodePipeline and at the build step we want to call an API hosted on an EC2 instance. That EC2 instance has a security group with some inbound rules. Is there any way to find out CIDR of the CodeBuild docker fleet, so we can add it to EC2 security group inbound rules, so that every stage from CodePipeline can call that API?

Comment: Are the docker instances that call the API in the same subnet or VPC?

Answer (score 3):

The range of public IP addresses used by the AWS CodeBuild build fleet is published here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html
You can use the published range for each region in your security group rules.

Comment: I have a very similar question here please Clare, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63725978/what-is-the-cidr-used-by-aws-codepipeline, where CodePipeline's IP ranges are not published in that document.