# What is the CIDR used by AWS CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to use GitHub's allow-list feature, where access to an organization's repositories can be restricted to only IPs in the allow-list.

I have a CodePipeline in `eu-west-2` (London) which is configured to have a source action of reading from GitHub.  I need the IP CIDR that is used by CodePipeline to perform the source clone, in order to add it to the allow-list. I have got the [AWS IP list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-download) and added all of the `CodeBuild` and `Amazon` service IPs in `eu-west-2` to the allow-list.  However, when I execute a build of the pipeline, it fails due to an inability to access the repository.

However, when I add `0.0.0.0/0` to the allow-list, the build works.  This would seem to indicate that CodePipeline is using either an unpublished range of IP addresses, or is somehow accessing GitHub from another region.

I have tried configuring CodePipeline to use S3 as a source and set logging on the bucket, in an attempt to capture the IP addresses being used by CodePipeline, but the IPs captured are internal IP addresses in the 172.16/12 space, i.e. they are not the external IP addresses used by CodePipeline.

What are the IP addresses used by CodePipeline?

Comment: I would say this is one for AWS support.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a reliable way to enumerate IPs used by CodePipeline.

However, please also note that CodePipeline is a public cloud service. If you allow-list all of CodePipeline, you'd effectively be allow-listing the whole world because anyone can sign up for and use CodePipeline.

I would focus on other techniques to harden your security, such as [rotating access tokens regularly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/GitHub-authentication.html#GitHub-rotate-personal-token-CLI). IP allow-listing often doesn't provide effective security in a cloud world ;)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use a VPC for your codebuild project, (the building docker container will run within a VPC subnets that you define) then you can use that VPC CIDR at your resource security group inbounds rules.

> Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) is a service that lets you launch
> AWS resources in a logically isolated virtual network that you define.

More information can be found here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/vpc-support.html